# How does GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER asynchronicity work?

Tags: opengl

If I understand correctly, when I use glGetTextureSubImage() OpenGL has to synchronize, before this function can return.

But if I bind a buffer to GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER that function call is asynchronous.

Does OpenGL synchronize it as soon as I try to access the data? Are there other rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does OpenGL synchronize it as soon as I try to access the data?

Yes; that's the whole point. When reading into your storage, the OpenGL implementation must assume that you will immediately access the read pixel data. It has to assume that because it cannot *detect* when you're about to read that storage. After all, OpenGL doesn't own that storage.

A buffer object is storage that OpenGL *owns*. If you call `glGetBufferSubData` or `glMapBufferRange` or whatever, OpenGL sees that call. Therefore, the OpenGL implementation can synchronize with the reading operation at that point, rather than at the time you issued the read.

Of course, with persistent mapping, OpenGL doesn't have the ability to tell when you're reading the data. But if you're using persistent mapping, you're telling OpenGL that *you* will perform the necessary synchronization, so it won't try to do so.